# What are the specs for the highest-end hard drive the WiiU can support?

Tags: wii-u

I am running out of space on my WiiU, and there are some games coming out soon that I will want to download.  I'd like to buy a new hard drive before that happens, but I don't know what kinds are supported and don't want to get something that's too good for it to use.

What are the specs for the best hard drive I can get for my WiiU?

Answer (score 2):

If you need more disk space for your WiiU, you need an external USB hard drive. Some facts about the WiiU and its USB:

- The WiiU's USB is 2.0, so don't bother with any USB 3.0 devices.
- WiiU can only access up to 2TB from an external device.
- No matter how fast the HDD is, the speed bottleneck will always be the USB 2.0 interface.

Get a 2TB USB drive with an external power supply and you should be okay. [Here is the official FAQ](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wiiu/en_na/system_external_storage.jsp) on the WiiU and external storage. It also lists external USB devices that are known to work.